# vector drawable not visible in api level 15 even after using the appCompat library version 23.3.0

Tags: android, svg, imageview, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

I am using a vector drawable in an ImageView in API level 15. I am using the AppCompat library version "appcompat-v7:23.3.0" in my gradle, which brings in the support of SVG for lower API levels.

Here is my XML for ImageView:

```
<ImageView
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/check"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivProduct"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/product_card_view_content_padding"
        android:id="@+id/ivAddedToCart"
        android:focusable="true"/>
```

This is the check.xml in drawable folder:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M9,16.2l-4.2,-4.2l-1.4,1.4l5.6,5.6l12,-12l-1.4,-1.4z"/>
```

The ImageView is not being displayed at all. Can anyone please tell what is the mistake I am doing.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your logcat?  Have you added `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to your build file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got where the problem was.
I was using  this

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

instead of this

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

in the parent layout.

Comment: Wow, that seriously affects the code I didn't realize it would be so easy to make a mistake like that